# Update boolean attributes to true or false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using the devise gem for authentication, and upon sign-in or signup, a cookie is created with:

```
cookies[:email] = {
  :value => params[:store][:email],
  :domain => :all,
  :expires => 1.hour.from_now
}
```

The purpose of the cookie is to find the `current_client`:

```
def current_client
  if cookies["email"].present?
   Store.find_by_email(params[:email])
  end
end
```

and then see if the store has an active or not braintree subscription,
and change the `is_active` boolean which is under the stores table to `true` or `false`.

```
after_action :active_subscription
def active_subscription
  if current_client.present?
    customer_id = current_client.braintree_customer_id
    customer = Braintree::Customer.find(customer_id )
    customer_card = customer.payment_methods[0].token
    payment_method = Braintree::PaymentMethod.find(customer_card)
    sub = payment_method.subscriptions[0]
    sub.status

  if Braintree::Subscription::Status::Active
     current_client.update_attributes(is_active: true)
  end
end
```

But the `active_subscription` method above does not update the `is_active` column. Any ideas on what I might be dong here wrong?

Comment: With your assignment of `cookies[:email]`, it will always be `present?`. Is that what you intend?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @sawa. Yes I need the `cookies[:email]` to always be present. Otherwise the app will not update the `is_active` column upon sign-in or sign-up

Comment: What is your condition `if cookies["email"].present?` for?

Comment: The purpose of the current_client method is to find the current_store that's trying to sign-in or sign-up and update the `is active` column under the stores table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple issues going on in the `active_subscription` method.

#### "If" test

The `if` check should compare the user's status to a constant:

```
# always passes because it's only looking at the constant!
if Braintree::Subscription::Status::Active

# instead, compare the client's status to the constant
if sub.status == Braintree::Subscription::Status::Active
```

#### Save failures

The `update_attributes` call may be failing due to validation errors. It returns false if save fails, which you may not be noticing.  You can raise an error instead by using `update_attributes!`:

```
current_client.update_attributes!(is_active: true)
```

If this is the problem, you can bypass validation checks by using [#update_attribute](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_attribute).

#### Other issues

1. Users' subscriptions could be in many states -- you may want to handle other values of `sub.status` and set `is_active` back to false if they're not active.
2. The `current_client` method checks to see if an "email" cookie is present, but then uses the email from `params[:email]`, not `cookies["email"]`. It should probably use `cookies` or `params`, not both!